# node ace configure is not a registered command in Adonisjs

Tags: internationalization, adonisjs-ace

I've been given an adonisjs project that has the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "adonis-api-app",
  "version": "4.1.0",
  "adonis-version": "4.1.0",
  "description": "Adonisjs boilerplate for API server with pre-configured JWT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "node ace test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "adonisjs",
    "adonis-app"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/ace": "^5.0.8",
    "@adonisjs/auth": "^3.0.7",
    "@adonisjs/bodyparser": "^2.0.5",
    "@adonisjs/cors": "^1.0.7",
    "@adonisjs/fold": "^4.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/framework": "^5.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/ignitor": "^2.0.8",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^6.1.3",
    "@adonisjs/mail": "^3.0.10",
    "@adonisjs/validator": "^5.0.6",
    "adonis-scheduler": "^3.0.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "nuxt-video-player": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "App": "./app"
  }
```

I've been asked to make the platform multilingual.  So I went to this website for instructions on how to implement i18n: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/i18n

As per the instructions, I installed with these commands:

```
npm i @adonisjs/i18n
node ace configure @adonisjs/i18n

  error: `configure` is not a registered command
```

How come my `node ace configure` doesn't work?  How do I correct the problem?

---

**UPDATE**

I think this means my adonisjs framework is from the year 2018.  And the earliest version of the i18n module is from 2021.   Which i18n module would be compatible with my version of the adonisjs framework?